# How to normalize different curves drawn with geom = "step" when using stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Here is my code. The data set is artificially generated to simulate data similar to my actual problem.

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
DataSet1 <- data.frame("Cat" = rep("A",10000), "Bin" = rep(c(-49:50),100), 
                       "Value" = c(seq(0,4.9, by=0.1),
                                   seq(4.9,0, by=-0.1)) * rep(rnorm(100,50,1),100))
DataSet2 <- data.frame("Cat" = rep("B",10000), "Bin" = rep(c(-49:50),100), 
                       "Value" = c(seq(0,4.9, by=0.1),
                                   seq(4.9,0, by=-0.1)) * rep(rnorm(100,75,1),100))
DataSet3 <- data.frame("Cat" = rep("C",10000), "Bin" = rep(c(-49:50),100), 
                       "Value" = c(seq(0,4.9, by=0.1),
                                   seq(4.9,0, by=-0.1)) * rep(rnorm(100,100,1),100))
DataSet <- rbind(DataSet1, DataSet2, DataSet3)

d <- ggplot(data = DataSet, aes(Bin, Value, color = Cat))
d + stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom = 'step', size = 1)
```

My result:

[image: Plotting the sum for each category at each bin]

What I want to do:

Normalize each of these plots, i.e., divide the sum at each bin width by the total Value for that curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, `stat_summary` is not meant to operate over all values of `x` and `y` simultaneously, so this type of per-group summary isn't possible strictly within ggplot. In cases such as this, it's usually best to compute your summary ahead of time and then plot that. Using **dplyr** to make summarization easy:

```
library(dplyr)

DataSet <- DataSet %>% 
  group_by(Cat, Bin) %>% 
  summarize(Value = sum(Value)) %>% 
  group_by(Cat) %>% 
  mutate(Value = Value / sum(Value))

d <- ggplot(data = DataSet, aes(Bin, Value, color = Cat))
d + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = 'step', size = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I was looking for. I do have a couple of questions though:
1. You are using  fun.y = mean because there is only one value, right? fun.y = mean or sum would be the same?
2. What if you have multiple cat columns such as cat1, cat2, etc. and you would want to separate color by cat1 and facet by cat2?

Comment: In that case, would it look like this:


`DataSet <- DataSet %>% 
  group_by(Cat1, Cat2, Bin) %>% 
  summarize(Value = sum(Value)) %>% 
  group_by(Cat1, Cat2) %>% 
  mutate(Value = Value / sum(Value))

d <- ggplot(data = DataSet, aes(Bin, Value, color = Cat1))
d + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = 'step', size = 1) + facet_grid(Cat2~.)`

Also, I really appreciate your help. This is my first time asking for help in the R community and it is great how helpful everyone is.